# Import ES6 module in browser from string in browser, instead of file

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am writing an offline-first coding education app that uses Babel, Webpack and React.  One of my goals is to allow students to write ES6 compliant javascript code with imports, in the browser.   I would like to let students write ES6 modules in a text editor, give them a name and treat them as modules that can be called from other ES6 modules.

I would prefer that they do not have to upload the code to a server, since this is an offline component.  I also would prefer to avoid Service Workers in the implementation, so that this works in more than just Chrome and Firefox.

I'm imaginig a component like this:

```
// React Component
import Babel from 'babel';
class JSEditor extends Component {

render(){

 module1;  // contains code from first module
 module2;  // contains code from second module

return (
<textarea>
let module1 = "const foo = 42;  export default foo;'; 
</textarea>

<textarea>
let module2 = "import foo from 'module1';  console.log(foo);" 
</textarea>

<button onclick={this.evalCode} />
)
 // what goes here?
evalCode() {
     let code1 = Babel.transform(this.module1);
     let code2 = Babel.transform(this.module2); 
     eval(code2);

 }
}
```

When I do Babel.transform in this way, it does not return or understand the module format I need.  How do I convince Babel to let me use modules without actual files involved?

Comment: Did you check out the [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&code=) (Read Evaluate Print Loop)? It might be just what you are looking for. Also maybe check out this service: https://repl.it/. And read [the Babel docs on running in the browser](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation).

Comment: Neither of those tools seem to support multiple "files"

Comment: I suggest looking at [es-module-loader](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es-module-loader). The README links to an example of using it in the browser that should be relatively easy to adapt to your purposes.

Comment: Rollup.js seems to be doing exactly what I want on their home page.  http://rollupjs.org/

Comment: I built a POC here using rollup, with some of the extraneous stuff stripped out https://github.com/tarr11/rollup-browser-poc